# jquery validate show 1 message with total number of errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Instead of showing a message under each form element, if there are more than 5 errors I would like to show 1 error message above the form with the total number of errors.

Reason: I have a large form and this can nearly double in height if there are lots of errors.

How would I get the total number of errors?

E.g something like this but this always returns 1.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var errorCount = 0;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < error.length; ++i) {
        errorCount++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: i think you should check your 'error' param. As i understand from this code you call this function for one field. So may be you need global 'errorCount' and increment it each time when checking field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [numberOfInvalids](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/numberOfInvalids) validation method.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/szaboat/Q3Mjg/1/

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this question, there was an error in szaboat's jsfiddle that caused a problem for me.

You need to pass a function to the `invalidHandler` option of the `validate()` method and the function should accept two arguments. The second argument is the validator itself which has a `numberOfInvalids()` method which returns the total error count.

Here is the example from the [jQuery Validation Plugin Documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler).

```
$("#myform").validate({
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // 'this' refers to the form
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
      var message = errors == 1
        ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
        : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
      $("div.error span").html(message);
      $("div.error").show();
    } else {
      $("div.error").hide();
    }
  }
});
```